# MySQL GROUP BY with additional conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm currently working with this MySQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs GROUP BY jobType, address1;
```

I need to be able to add another condition to this query. GROUP BY only combines duplicates, but I also need to combine all rows that have a jobType of '1' or a jobType of '2'. All other jobTypes will be grouped normally.

For example, my table looks something like this:

```
jobType | address1
1       | 123 State st
2       | 123 State st
3       | 415 5th Ave
1       | 123 State st
1       | 24 3rd Ave
1       | 123 State st
3       | 555 Mission st
4       | 123 State st
```

I want to combine rows 1 and 2, even though their jobType is different. Again, any rows with a jobType other than either 1 or 2 would be grouped normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN jobType in ('1','2') THEN '1' ELSE jobType END, address1
```